# How to remove the character from the numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL 2008

```
ID: C/213434343434334, CA/2566121212122
```

From the above id, i want to take only numbers. How to acheive this

Required Output

```
213434343434334, 2566121212122
```

Need Query Help

Comment: It does appear to be a duplicate, but I can't see any reference in that question to using CLR, which I think is the best solution. [This page](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/04/27/SQL-2005-Regular-Expression-Replace.aspx) contains an example for `RegexReplace` using CLR.

Answer (score 2):

try this way

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(400)
DECLARE @expres  VARCHAR(50) = '%[a-z,/]%'
SET @str = 'CA/2566121212122'
WHILE PATINDEX( @expres, @str ) > 0
SET @str = Replace(REPLACE( @str, SUBSTRING( @str, PATINDEX( @expres, @str ), 1 ),''),'-',' ')

SELECT @str
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT substring(ID,charindex('/',ID)+1,len (ID)-charindex('/',ID))  New_Id
FROM [YOUR TABLE]
```

Answer (score 0):

If all characters will be in front of the special character '/', you can use the following:

```
DECLARE @ID1 nvarchar(200) = 'C/213434343434334', 
        @ID2 nvarchar(200) = 'CA/2566121212122'


SELECT RIGHT(@ID1, CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(@ID1))-1)
SELECT RIGHT(@ID2, CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(@ID2))-1)
```

RESULTS:

```
RESULT @ID1 : 213434343434334
RESULT @ID2 : 2566121212122
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Use SUBSTRING() to get the result.

```
CREATE TABLE #Test
(
 ID NVARCHAR(MAX) 
)

INSERT INTO #Test
SELECT 'C/213434343434334' UNION
SELECT 'CA/2566121212122'

SELECT SUBSTRING(ID, CHARINDEX('/', ID)+ 1, LEN(ID)) AS ID FROM #Test
```

Comment: You are assuming that there where always be a `/` in the ID